# best practise to init member

Tags: python, oop

I have a question on best practises to initialise a class. Consider a class that is complex and has *a lot of members*. It's bad practise to init them outside of `__init__()`, but how can I handle the problem without having an enormous `__init__()` method.

An example:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self):
       self.member0 = "a"

       # to prevent that the init method gets too big
       # put some initialisation outside
       init_other_stuff()

   def init_other_stuff(self):
       self.member1 = "b"
       self.member2 = "c"
       ...
```

Thanks in advance.

**[update]** To clarify. The goal is not to put the stuff into another long method of course. Instead you can split the initialisation into different parts like:

```
def init_network_stuff(self):
    """ init network setup """
    self.my_new_socket = socket.socket(..)


def init_local_stuff(self):
    """ init local setup """
    self.my_new_logpath = "/foo/bar/log"

...
```

Comment: Where is the problem? I can not see how a large `__init__` is different from your 'solution'. Introducing another method only creates the problem of this method being callable.

Comment: It's hard to give a definite answer.  In my opinion, simply cutting off `__init__()` and moving the rest of the function to another function simply to prevent it from becoming "too long" is quite pointless.  Additionally, I think a class with lots of members is a sign of a design problem by itself.

Comment: *Consider a class that is complex and has a lot of members.* That's your problem right there. The class shouldn't have that many attributes. Maybe you should be looking at redesigning your class system.

Comment: so in order to avoid having a long __init__, you move its content to another long method (that anyone could call without really realizing it is an init method ?)

Comment: It does not make any sense to add the methods, because it would be nonsensical to call them outside of `__init__`. At the very least, they should be `_underscore_method`s

Answer (score 0):

I would also agree that having too many attributes is probably a sign of insufficient abstraction, which is usually harder to develop & debug, and so changing your design is probably a good idea.

But, you do have a gold badge, so you've obviously been around and (probably) know what you are doing, and might have a reason to do this. In that case, I think it's a good idea to split up the initialization by category like you suggested. The only suggestion I would have is to use _ on the sub-init functions to signal to a user they aren't intended for normal use i.e.

```
class A:
def __init__(self):
    self.member0 = "a"

    self.__init_other_stuff()

def __init_other_stuff(self):
   self.member1 = "b"
   self.member2 = "c"
```

etc. This also hides them from tab-completion in most consoles & editors.

Your other choice is to make this class a subclass of multiple classes that implement part of the interface if you really need A to contain those items directly, i.e. do something like this:

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logparam = 1

class NetworkSource(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.netparam = 2

class A(Logger, NetworkSource):
    def __init__(self):
        Logger.__init__(self)
        NetworkSource.__init__(self)

In [2]: a = A()

In [3]: a.<tab>
a.logparam a.netparam
```

Then it would get the functionality of both classes, while having a relatively short init. Multiple inheritance is conceptually a little more complicated though IMHO.